# How to trace and to kill all applications, querying web in background?

Tags: windows-10, http, web

While trying to debug my application with Fiddler 4, I found, that numerous applications querying web constantly, creating an obstacles for me to find usefull queries.

Examples of queries are:

https://nexus.officeapps.live.com/nexus/upload/...

https://play.google.com/log...

https://4.client-channel.google.com/client-channel/channel/bind?authuser=1&ctype=hangouts...

http://travel.tile.appex.bing.com/api/livetile.xml?language=en-US&region=RU

and so on.

Is it possible to find all such applications and kill/terminate them in bulk?

Comment: Don't set the system proxy... instead set your application's proxy to use Fiddler?

Comment: Yes, but I want to get rid of backround senders anyway

Comment: Do you know the target domain? You could setup a filter: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/Filters